# why reusing SparkContext speeds query up so much

Tags: apache-spark

In my spark job, I create a SparkContext, load my data via Parquet files, then use spark sql to process them. When I open a spark shell, the 1st time I run a query it takes quite long time, around 200 secs in my case. Then I keep the spark shell open, and run the same query, also some other different queries on the same dataset, it only takes 20-30 secs~, it roughly gains 10x faster performance.

Can Someone give me a detailed explanation on this? Is one spark shell keeps using one SparkContext? If that's the case, how exactly reusing SparkContext speeds things up so much.

Comment: Can you please share the code. So that we can explain it in a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that Spark stores intermediate files on local disk while the context is open.  Once the intermediate files are stored, Spark can do a local read to the files on local disk, as opposed to doing a read from the HDFS.

You can validate this by opening the Spark UI and navigating to the DAG schedule.  You'll see some of your stages are grey, and some are blue.  The grey ones should say stage skipped.  That means that the data for that stage was already available.

Comment: So, it only store intermediate files? so next query will load the intermediate files to memory and form the RDD again? not load them in RDD once, and the following queries just access the RDD? that should be faster, right?

Comment: Spark stores intermediate files when it does a shuffle operation.  RDD's never physically exist, unless they are explicitly cached by the developer.  RDD's are a recipe on how to process data, so when you think of an RDD, think more of an rdd as a set of operations to apply to data.  Now when you execute a query, data must be processed and shuffled at some point.  If you execute the same query twice, instead of going back to the base data on the storage system, it will pick up the latest set of intermediate files to avoid extra recomputations.

Comment: @ Joe Widen thanks for the explanations. Can this also explain different query on the same data gets a lot faster ?

Comment: Exactly.  If you were to query a different data set, the time would go back to being slower as well.